# Error drawing pie chart with veteran data

Tags: r

I have to Draw a pie chart for `celltype` of the data `veteran` from package `survival`.

My attempt is

```
     data(veteran, package = "survival")

     with(veteran,pie(celltype,labels=c(squamous,adeno,large,smallcell)))
     Error in pie(celltype, labels = c(squamous, adeno, large, smallcell)) : 
    'x' values must be positive.
```

How can i draw pie chart for `celltype` of the data `veteran` from package `survival`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the function `pie()` you should provide numeric vector not the raw data of `celltype`. Use `table()` to calculate number of occurrences. In this case you don't need to provide labels as the will be displayed automatically.

```
with(veteran,pie(table(celltype)))
```